# How to fix this error I encountered while creating and accessing a remote repository in GitHub through VS code

Tags: git, github

[image: error]

This error is occurring when I'm trying to access a remote repository from my VS Code terminal, it seems to work on my friend's device but I'm facing this problem when i try to execute it.

Tried to delete the repository and recreated it on both GitHub and on my local machine, deleted previous instances and tried again, And I ended up with the same error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+src+refspec+main+does+not+match+any

Answer (score 1):

The error message you're seeing, `src refspec main does not match any`, suggests that you're trying to push a branch named `main` to the remote repository, but Git can't find a branch with that name in your local repository.

In the screenshot, you've run `git status` which shows that you're currently on the `master` branch. This implies that your local repository does not have a branch named `main`, which is why the push is failing.